# How to crop with edge-detection using imagemagick

Tags: edge-detection

Let's say I have an image of an object against a white background. I want to crop so that the image fills the available space.
This takes 10px off:

```
convert original.png -shave 10x10 shaved.png
```

How would I implement something like this that detects the edges of the object, thus cropping a variable number of pixels from each side?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it appears to be about using image processing software, not about computer graphics programming and research. [This might be on topic on Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/imagemagick).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `-trim` instead of `-shave`:

```
convert original.png -trim trimmed.png
```

See the [docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#trim) for this and other options.

Comment: Thanks, the docs recommended a fuzz factor. Combined with shaving border artifacts it worked perfectly. `convert original.png -shave 5x5 -fuzz 1% -trim +repage trimmed.png`